# Pass arguments with UIViewController when setting up TabviewController in AppDelegate

Tags: ios

When I create the tab in the tab bar I want to pass with it arguments.  These arguments will change each time the app starts.  However I get Property 'passedURL' not found on object of type 'UIViewController'  at

```
finalVC.passedURL = @"http://www.google.com";
```

FinalCategoryVC.h:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *passedURL;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "FinalCategoryVC.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    UIViewController  *finalVC = [[[FinalCategoryVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FinalCategoryVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    finalVC.passedURL = @"http://www.google.com";

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];   
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[finalVC]; 
   self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you're casting your FinalCategoryVC to a UIViewController with this line,

```
UIViewController  *finalVC = [[[FinalCategoryVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FinalCategoryVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Change it to this to fix the problem,

```
FinalCategoryVC  *finalVC = [[[FinalCategoryVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FinalCategoryVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```